# Memory manipulation in C

Tags: c

I have an algorithm I would like to try get working, I guess you could call it pseudo C because it doesn't compile.

```
void framebufferClearScreen (framebufferColor color) {
  unsigned int pixelSize = (systemFramebuffer->bpp >> 3);
  unsigned int lineSize = (systemFramebuffer->width * pixelSize);
  unsigned char *address = (unsigned char *)(systemFramebuffer->buffer);
  unsigned char *maxaddress = (unsigned char *)(address + (systemFramebuffer->height * systemFramebuffer->pitch) + (systemFramebuffer->height * lineSize));

  while (address != maxaddress) {
    // Set the memory based on pixel size
    if (systemFramebuffer->bpp == 32) {
      (unsigned char[4]*)address = 0xFF112233;
    } else if (systemFramebuffer->bpp == 24) {
      (unsigned char[3]*)address = 0x112233;
    } else if (systemFramebuffer->bpp == 16) {
      (unsigned char[2]*)address = 0x1223;
    }

    // move to next location
    address += pixelSize;

    // If at end of line, add extra pitch
    if (address % lineSize == 0) {
      address += systemFramebuffer->pitch;
    }
  }
}
```

So my first issue is I have no idea how to set a c type that is a specific size, `(unsigned char[3]*)` I know doesn't work but I have no idea what would be a valid 3 byte system independent sized data type, for example.

The other bit is `address % lineSize` is also invalid.

What do I need to do to make this work?

My compiler is `arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.7.4 20140401 (release)`.

Comment: I think you need to go and read about basic C syntax and semantics. This stuff unlikely to work as you expect even after you fix the syntax.

Comment: For the 32 and 16 bit variants, use `uint32_t` and `uint16_t` (see e.g. [this fixed-width integer reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for information about those types). Like simply `((uint32_t *) address) = 0x........`. For the 24-bit you probably have to do some manual solution where you set each byte individually. Can be simplified with a function or even a macro (though I recommend an `inline` function for it).

Comment: When filling a framebuffer to a fixed color, you only need to duplicate the same 12 byte sequence to the entire framebuffer. If you have 8 bits per pixel, then all those bytes are the same, specifying the color for 12 pixels. If you have 16 bits per pixel, then those bytes specify the color for 6 consecutive pixels. If you have 24 bits per pixel, then those bytes specify the color for 4 consecutive pixels. If you have 32 bits per pixel, then those bytes specify the color for 3 consecutive pixels. So, you only need a function that can copy a 12-byte sequence over the entire framebuffer.

Comment: If 4-byte pixels are the largest pixel size, then just use a 4-byte variable `unsigned char pixel[4]`.  Use the low `pixelSize` bytes in your code.

Comment: @NominalAnimal How do you deal with the pitch at the end of each line?

Comment: @Justin808: By ignoring it. The framebuffer aperture consists of rows of pixels, where each row is the same size (`pitch` bytes), and starts at offset `row * pitch`. The possible padding at the end of the row is unused, and only exists when the hardware prefers each row to start at an aligned address. The padding never contains non-pixel data. It is easy for hardware manufacturers to set the devices up this way, and framebuffer libraries definitely expect this, so this just happens to be the way all normal/ordinary framebuffer hardware is expected to work.

Comment: @Justin808: Note that there are display devices with odd requirements, that nevertheless might provide a somewhat framebuffer-like interface. Some e-ink devices could be such. However, they also tend to have other, weirder requirements (like update types and restrictions on e-ink devices) that means you cannot use a general-purpose framebuffer library on them anyway -- unless you bolt on a lot of extra functionality on top. In which case it's better to create a specialized library anyway. You mentioned no hardware quirks, so I assumed you know of none. (Most often there are none.)